# Why must the rational numbers be fixed on any automorphism of $\mathbb R$?

Tags: model-theory

I'm studying Model theory using David Marker's "Model Theory: An Introduction".

In the first chapter he presents the following proposition:

> Proposition 1.3.5:
>
> Let $\cal M$ be an $\cal L$-structure. If $X\subseteq M^n$ is $A$-definable, then every $\cal L$-automorphism of $\cal M$ that fixes $A$ pointwise fixes $X$ setwise.

and after this, he gives an example that, in the languange of rings $\mathcal{ L }= \{+,-,\cdot, 0,1\}$, the only automorphism of $\mathcal{ M}=(\mathbb  R,+,-,\cdot,0,1)$ is the indentity. The argument is as follows:

> "Any automorphism of the real field must fix the rational numbers. Because the order is $\emptyset$-definalbe it must be preserved by the automorphism. Because the rationals are dense, the only automorphism is the identity".

I understand why the order must be preserved, and I understand why "order being preserved" + "rationals being fixed" $\implies$ "any automorphism is the identity", but I'm having some trouble understanding why the rational numbers must be fixed by the automorphism.

Why is this the case?

Comment: ...because each rational number is (individually) $\emptyset$-definable, e.g., $2/3 = (1+1)/(1+1+1)$ (or if you insist $2/3$ is the unique real number $x$ such that $(1+1+1)x = 1+1$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's a field automorphism it must fix $0$ and $1$ as those are the only two numbers equal to their own square.  That in turn fixes any two integers $n$ and $m$ as $1+1$ $n$ or $m$ times, which in turn fixes any rational $n/m$.

Comment: You are right. I was so focused on the Model-theoretic properties of the automorphism that I forgot that it's also a field isomorphism. thx

Comment: A simpler way to observe $0$ and $1$, is: group automorphisms always fix the identity.

Comment: Yes, but in this case, 0 and 1 are fixed by the definition of automorphism @MJD